# python- Related Object Does Not Exist at /admin/login/

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm having a problem logging into my localhost:8000/admin/ page, after entering the correct username and password, I get the "Related Object Does Not Exist at /admin/login/" error and it says the "User does not exist" but it being the admin is my main cause for worry.
I removed the "django.contrib.sites" package following advice I got on a previous error.
I'm using django 2.0.2 and python 3.6.
settings.py:

```
 # Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'nutrients.apps.NutrientsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'profile',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'nutrition.urls'

CMS_TEMPLATES = ('index.html', 'Left sidebar template')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'nutrition.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 2.0.2
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['nutrients.apps.NutrientsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'profile']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:
    Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/admin/

Django Version: 2.0.2
Python Version: 3.6.5
Installed Applications:
['nutrients.apps.NutrientsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'profile']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in login
  398.         return LoginView.as_view(**defaults)(request)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in dispatch
  65.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  142.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py" in form_valid
  94.         auth_login(self.request, form.get_user())

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in login
  161.     user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in send
  178.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  178.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py" in update_last_login
  20.     user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py" in save
  73.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  729.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  769.                 update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in send
  178.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  178.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\PycharmProjects\nutrition\nutrients\models.py" in save_user_profile
  32.         instance.profile.save()

File "C:\Users\Kanverse\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  389.                     self.related.get_accessor_name()

Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /admin/login/
Exception Value: User has no profile..
```

any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why didn't you mention that you are using Django-CMS? Did you read the [requirements](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/install.html#requirements)?

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: It wasn't my intention to use a CMS, I don't seem to recognize as much in the code, kindly indicate where??

Comment: I've added full traceback